# Delete or delete[] over new int[][]

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I know in general if you `new` an instance of an object or a primary data type, you use `delete`; if you allocate an array such as `new int[10]`, you free the memory by `delete[]`. I just came across [another source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16239446/4713342) and find out that in C++11, you can new a multidimensional array like this:

```
auto arr = new int[10][10];
```

My question is: Should I use `delete` or should I use `delete[]`? I would say `delete[]` looks more correct for me, however, `delete` doesn't crash the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        cout << i << endl;
        auto ptr = new int[300][300][300];
        ptr[299][299][299] = i;
        delete ptr;  // both delete and delete[] work fine here
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Why is that?

Comment: it doesn't crash it but does it correctly free the memory?

Comment: If it doesn't free the memory, after so many rounds, how can the program survive?

Comment: are results the same if you use "int *" instead of "auto"?

Comment: @TimeString Clang, for starters, optimizes that whole new/delete business away. It also tells you what you should use. https://godbolt.org/g/dfa0uk

Comment: As far as I know, the type of ptr should be `int (*)[300][300]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Always `delete[]` when the object allocated is an array (including an array of arrays, *i.e.,* a multidimensional array). Using `delete` when you are supposed to use `delete[]`, or *vice versa,* is undefined behaviour. It may appear to work but there is no guarantee.

Comment: I'm more interested in what's going on after I do `new int[100][100]`: Does it allocate a continuous memory segment or does it allocate 100 segments, each segment contains 100 elements?

Comment: @TimeString Please post a new question

Comment: It seems `int (*ptr)[100][100] = new int[100][100][100];` first creates an array of pointer of int[100][100], but the later two dimensions int[100][100] seem to be a contiguous segment.

Comment: @TimeString No, it does not. It has to be just 100 `int[100][100]` arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You could new such array before C++11.

```
    int (*p)[300][300] = new int[300][300][300];
```

C++11 only gives 'auto' sugar.

This is not three-dimentionally dynamic array, it is dynamic only by first direction, i.e. dymamic array of two-dimentional statio arrays.

You can say

```
    auto p = new int[rand()][300][300];
```

But you can't say

```
    auto p = new int[300][rand()][300];
```

So since this is ordinary dynamic array, use ordinary delete []